# Fgets and EOF in C

Tags: c, eof, fgets

I need to know how to read all records from file using fgets i dont understand how to read all records with while loop. Because if i write loop like this i get runtime error what can be the fault? Thank you.

```
N=15;     
sakums:  
 struct studenti students[N];     
       char line[100];
   char *ptk; char * end; int i;int sorted;
    int g=0,ch,count=0;
    int n;
    int choice;
   FILE *fails_st = fopen("studenti.txt", "r+");
    printf("\n1.Show data  ");   
 scanf("%d",&choice); 
if(choice==1)
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fails_st) != NULL)         
   {               
     students[i].Nr = strtol(line, &end, 10);
     ptk = strtok(line, " ");
     ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
     strcpy(students[i].name, ptk);
     ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
     strcpy(students[i].surname, ptk);
     ptk = strtok(NULL, ".");
     end = (ptk + strlen(ptk));
     students[i].dzd.da_day = strtol(ptk, &end, 10);
     ptk = strtok(NULL, ".");
     end = (ptk + strlen(ptk));
     students[i].dzd.da_month = strtol(ptk, &end, 10);
     ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
     end = (ptk + strlen(ptk));
     students[i].dzd.da_year = strtol(ptk, &end, 10);
     ptk = strtok(NULL, " ");
     students[i].dzimums = *ptk;
   }
   fclose(fails_st);
       printf("Student list\n");
   printf("%d. %s %s %d.%d.%d %c\n", students[i].Nr, students[i].name, 
          students[i].surname, students[i].dzd.da_day, 
          students[i].dzd.da_month, students[i].dzd.da_year, 
          students[i].dzimums);
```

My first loop was like this, but it checks only constant count of records.

```
  for(i=0; i < N && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fails_st) != NULL; i++)
```

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your code or are you asking us to teach you how read data into a file? If you want us to debug your code, we need to know at least what `N` is and what data you fed it. (Also, if you want us to debug your code, start by removing any code that's not relevant. Test to see what code you can remove and most likely, you'll find the bug yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have more than `N` records in the file.  Currently you are overflowing your array as soon as you read more.  You will need to use dynamic memory allocation:

```
struct studenti *students = NULL;
int max_students = 0;
int num_students = 0;
const int grow_amount = N;

while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fails_st) ) {
    if( num_students >= max_students ) {
        max_students += grow_amount;
        students = realloc( students, max_students * sizeof(struct studenti) );
    }

    // TODO: Read data into students[num_students]

    num_students++;
}

// When done with the memory, don't forget to free it.
free(students);
```

Comment: It is so tempting to downvote you for putting spaces on the inside of your parentheses.  Or for linear rather than exponential reallocation. Or for using overly verbose loop index variable names.

Comment: About the spaces on the inside of the parentheses? Absolutely. That style makes my eyes bleed.  (But you will note that I did not actually downvote you.)

Comment: The only valid point you made was about linear *vs* exponential growth, which is fair enough.  I figure that for this program, the number of students is likely to be close enough to `N` that it makes little difference.  Every other point is absurd.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for answer. How can fix the error for this ' students = realloc( students, max_students * sizeof(struct studenti) );'invalid conversion from void* to studenti*

Comment: @user2883601 That error indicates you are compiling C code as if it were C++.  Correct the extension on your source file(s) to `.c` and it should go away.  If you actually intended to write a C++ program, junk all of this and use `vector<studenti>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is *not* with `fgets`.  Rather, it is with this part:

```
struct studenti students[N];
```

If you want to support an arbitrary number of records, you will need to make this a dynamic allocation, and resize it (using `realloc`) whenever you hit the current size limit.  That code would look something like this:

```
size_t max_students = N;
size_t i = 0;
struct studenti *students = malloc(max_students * sizeof(struct studenti));
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fails_st))
{
    if (i == max_students)
    {
        max_students *= 2;
        students = realloc(students, max_students * sizeof(struct studenti));
    }
    /* parse `line` into `students[i]` as you are currently doing */
    i++;
}
```

Error handling left as an exercise.